# "Adding" new fonts to Tesseract eng.traineddata

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

As far as I know, Tesseract 3.x comes with 6 English (correct me if I'm wrong) fonts. I need to train Tesseract for more 5 types of fonts. I need only capital letters and digits (no special characters or symbols).

I followed various processes for example:
[Adding New Fonts to Tesseract 3 OCR Engine](http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine)

and also used tools to automate the process like
[Serak Tesseract Trainer for Tesseract 3.02](http://code.google.com/p/serak-tesseract-trainer/)

For generating box files I used [QT Box Editor](http://zdenop.github.io/qt-box-editor/)

After using above tools I get `eng.traineddata` file. All tutorials tell me to add this `eng.traineddata` file to the `Tesseract-OCR\tessdata` folder, but doing so, it will replace the original `eng.traineddata` file. After doing this will I lose the default fonts that come with Tesseract 3.x ?

How can I Add new fonts? Its still not clear to me. I hope someone can help me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Should use a different name, e.g., `eng1.traineddata`. That way you can use the new data with the original one by specifying the language option `-l eng+eng1`.

Comment: where can i specify the language option -l eng+eng1 ?

Comment: This might sound too lazy but is there a way to provide a font file as input (to a website, say) and a trained `tessdata` is provided as output?

Comment: @tipycalFlow [jTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html) has a TIFF/Box Generator. You can provide a font file and get a box with the correct values. With [Serak Tesseract Trainer](http://code.google.com/p/serak-tesseract-trainer/) you can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you have new trained data with different font, I think you don't have dictionary correction for your new font.

To add new trained data you can do this (I'm using PHP code here)

```
//  as you new trained data, it must be 3 letter prefix 
// what ever 3 letter you want
$languange = "eng+deu";
$settingLanguage = $tesseract -> setLanguage($language) ;
```

By seeing the tesseract.php function `setLanguage()`, you can set the language by that function.