# Tesseract ocr training

Tags: tesseract, overwrite, training-data

Was wondering if I used this method [The method for Tesseract training](http://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine/)
To add new fony style as eng letters.

- will It overwrite the original fonts I already had ?
- Or it will be added to the existing fonts that was brought with Tesseract by default with installation?

Thanks a lot
Max

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332986/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-eng-traineddata/

Comment: Thanks way much. Appreciate it